# SQL concept: nested loop

Tags: mysql, sql

1. `Teacher (userID, name, DOB, gender, email, address, phoneNo, password, highestQual, isAdmin)`
2. `Lesson (lessonID, lessonFee, <teacherID>, <subjectID>)`
3. `Enroll (<studentID>, <lessonID>, <paymentID>,result)`

Suppose that running the below SQL will return two tuple with identical `teacherID`.

```
SELECT teacherID FROM tuition.Lesson WHERE lessonID IN(
                SELECT lessonID FROM tuition.Lesson WHERE lessonID NOT IN ((
                SELECT distinct lessonID FROM tuition.Enroll ))
                );
```

[image]

But if I want to select the names for display, the result will return one tuple instead of two.

```
SELECT name FROM tuition.teacher WHERE userID IN (
                SELECT teacherID FROM tuition.Lesson WHERE lessonID IN(
                SELECT lessonID FROM tuition.Lesson WHERE lessonID NOT IN ((
                SELECR distinct lessonID FROM tuition.Enroll )))
                );
```

What can I do so that my result will display two tuple, the same name being displayed twice. Please help advise.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Pick the right tag please

Comment: Most probably MySQL, from the result pic attached in post.

Answer (score 0):

`tuition.teacher` has only record with `userID teacher1` and so you are getting one record. That's perfectly correct. You should use a `distinct` clause in your first query to get only unique `teacherID` like `SELECT distinct teacherID FROM tuition.Lesson ...`

If you forcefully want to duplicate the result, then use  `UNION` clause like

```
SELECT name FROM tuition.teacher WHERE userID IN (
                SELECT teacherID FROM tuition.Lesson WHERE lessonID IN(
                SELECT lessonID FROM tuition.Lesson WHERE lessonID NOT IN ((
                SELECR distinct lessonID FROM tuition.Enroll )))
                )

UNION ALL

SELECT name FROM tuition.teacher WHERE userID IN (
                SELECT teacherID FROM tuition.Lesson WHERE lessonID IN(
                SELECT lessonID FROM tuition.Lesson WHERE lessonID NOT IN ((
                SELECR distinct lessonID FROM tuition.Enroll )))
                )
```

Comment: but i do not require my results to be distinct :/ in fact, i need two names to be return (even if they are the same name)

Comment: As mentioned you have only one record in `teacher` table with that teacherID and so there is no question of getting >1 record. If you forcefully want that, then use a `UNION`. See edit in answer.